# Please explain the sentence structure of 高高的举起手 (Raise your hand high)

Tags: grammar, sentence

One tool translates "Raise your hand high" as 高举你的手, which seems logical (high raise your hand).  But another source says it is 高高的举起手.  Why is 高 repeated, and what is the purpose of 的 in this sentence?

Comment: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Reduplication_of_adjectives

Comment: Shouldn't it be 地 instead of 的?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not from a gramattical standpoint).

高举你的手 is more imperative but it sounds really weird (nobody says this, perople will say something like 把手举高).

高高地举起手 sounds more polite and feel like it's someone talking to kindergardeners. Repeating the character puts more emphasis on the adjective high. The 的 is just to connect the adjective and he action, for instance, you could also say 快乐地举起手, raising their hands happily.

Something like  高地举起手would not be correct though

Comment: Shouldn't it be 地 instead of 的?

Comment: @noe you're correct, forgot about it, fixed it